# Is it possible to change the way Resharper 4.5 formats code in aspx/ascx files?

Tags: c#, resharper

I find myself constantly pressing ctrl-z to undo the automatic formatting that happens in templates. For example Resharper would like to format a foreach loop like this:

```
<%
  foreach (var product in Model.Items)
  { %>
      <li><%= product.Name %></li>
<% } %>
```

This is fine in c# code files but it just seems messy in templates.
I would prefer to format it like this

```
<% foreach (var product in Model.Items) { %>
    <li><%= product.Name %></li>
<% } %>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open Visual Studio
Goto
Resharper > Options... > Langauges > C# > Formatting Style > Braces Layout > Other

Change to "At end of line (no space)"

Note this will affect your C# as well.

It is a bit annoying that you cant specify a different code sytle for you aspx pages since its often you do want something differnt.

Answer (score 1):

Resharper does not allow you to create custom formatting. You can only change the predefined formatting under options. I poked around and did not see <% %> formatting options. Sorry :(

Answer (score 0):

Starting from ReSharper 7.1 (currently at EAP), there is an option to use K&R style in ASP and Razor while continuing to use BSD for C#. ReSharper | Options -> Code Editing | ASP.NET | Editor & Formatting -> Override brace style for C# to always use "At end of line (K&R style)"