# VS2008: Is it possible to have custom formatting for @ directives?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, formatting

In VS2008 (Tools -> Options, Text Editor, HTML, Format, Tag Specific Options) you can control the automatic formatting of most tags.

However, I'd like to have VS automatically format my @p Page directive so that instead of:

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="Foo.aspx.vb" Inherits="WebRoot.Foo"
   MasterPageFile="~/WebRoot.Master" %>
```

I get:

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" 
         CodeBehind="Foo.aspx.vb" 
         Inherits="WebRoot.Foo"
         MasterPageFile="~/WebRoot.Master" 
%>
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can control the Page and Register directives the same way as other tags.

Tools > Options
Text Editor > HTML > Format > Tag Specific Options > ASP.NET Controls

**Page**
Scroll and find Page (<%@ Page)

**Register**
Add a new tag for Register (<%@ Register)

Comment: In VS2008, there doesn't seem to be any way to control the formatting of the attributes within the tags.

Answer (score 0):

I thought [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) might let you do something like this, but it looks like you can't do custom formatting rules; only the presets it comes with. ([See this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/853671/is-it-possible-to-change-the-way-resharper-4-5-formats-code-in-aspx-ascx-files/853726#853726))

But you should be able use a regex tool to do this, or maybe write a macro to run when you build your project.